# How can I create nested dynamic component based on value of string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a dynamic component in React, based on the value of a string variable, but am having problems.

If I supply the following it works fine:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="App">
    <XYPlot height={500} width={800}>
      <AreaSeries data={localData} />
    </XYPlot>
  </div>,
  container
);
```

But, if I do the following, nothing renders. The SeriesComponent looks fine in the console, so I guess I'm just not dynamically inserting it correctly - what should I do instead?

```
var chart_type = 'AreaSeries'; // I have no control over this - it has to be a string.
const SeriesComponent = React.createElement(
    chart_type, {data: localData}
);
console.log('seriesComponent', seriesComponent);
ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="App">
    <XYPlot height={500} width={800}>
      {SeriesComponent}
    </XYPlot>
  </div>,
  container
);
```

Comment: Read https://reactjs.org/docs/implementation-notes.html. The option of passing `string` as the parameter is for *platform-specific (“host”) components*. Those would be `div`, `span`,`h1` etc.. normal DOM elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way that I know is something like this,first create a `chartTypes` and insert 
all of your chartypes in it forExample

```
const chartTypes = {
     AreaSeries, //this name is name of component also
}
```

also import `AreaSeries` component

```
import AreaSeries from 'something'
```

then

```
const SeriesComponent = React.createElement(
  chartTypes.AreaSeries, {data: localData}
);
```

**Remember it is important to import `AreaSeries` to use with chartype.**

you can see this [SandBox Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/6xwm7rwylr) that I created.

**Updated**
You say you no control over string but this is a custom component not something like `span` that React can create it for you. so some scenario happen.scenario one is to map your string with object of `charTypes` for example

```
const chartTypes = {
  something:AreaSeries,
  something2:AreaSeries,
  something2:AreaSeries2
}
```

and also you need to import AreaSeries or anything that you know maybe it needs to render.so if `something` or `something2` happen it renders `AreaSeries`.
maybe you see why I need to import all of my components do you know any better way? 
another way is load component async but still you need charTypes to know which component you should to load asynchronously

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how to apply that to my example. I have updated the question to make it a bit clearer that I'm starting with a string and need to create the component dynamically to match the string.